# mvn spring-boot:run -P<profile> while official guide recommend other command to launch profile?

Tags: java, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-profiles

When implementing a profile in spring boot application,
with something like that in a pom.xml :

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>debug</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>debug</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
                   ..
                   ..
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

What i don't understand is :
when i launch my application with

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Pdebug
```

ALL IS FINE. BUT :
when i respect the official guide, it never works  :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/pdf/spring-boot-maven-plugin-reference.pdf

The official guide says to use this command :

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dapp.profiles=debug
```

or

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.profiles=debug
```

So, why my method, which is not recommended by official guide, works ?
why official method does not work ?

Comment: Maven profile is not the same as a Spring Boot profile. You are conflating different things. Maven profiles specify optional parts of the build. Spring Boot profiles specify optional parts of the application.

Comment: it all makes sense now !